# Loading Pages with Ajax, need to execute javascript with PHP call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using [this script](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) to load pages on my site (Wordpress CMS).  In order to execute javascript scripts on the page, I have to include them in the above script, otherwise they will not load.  Here is what I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

/* Other Stuff to load page, etc. */

    var feed = new Instafeed({
       get: 'user',
       userId: <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'instagramuserID', true ); ?>,
       accessToken: '<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'instagramToken', true ); ?   >',
       limit: 3,
       template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>'
       });
       feed.run();
}
```

When I run this code I get an error

> Unexpected token ?

I understand why this is happening (php should not be client side) but I can't figure out a work around.  I need those php functions in order to retrieve the values for the script. I've heard mention of using json to retrieve the values, but I'm not sure how to work that into the existing script.

Comment: I figured it out.  There is a div class (document script) that you can wrap the script in that will reload it once the page HTML has been loaded.  It helps to completely read a script before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

is this typo? `?   >` fix it to `?>`and try again